# Using WebKit for SWT Browser inside Eclipse plugin

Tags: webkit, swt, eclipse-rcp

I tried today to use the WebKit as the Browser's underlying renderer for my eclipse plugin but no luck.

I followed the [recommended instructions](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#howusewebkit) and my current environment is as follows:

- OS: Windows 7 (x64)
- Safari installed (in the PATH too)
- 32 bit SWT (eclipse RCP indigo SR1 32)

added the following line to eclipse.ini

> -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=webkit

Now when I try to instantiate the browser:

```
Browser b = new Browser(parent, SWT.WEBKIT);
b.setUrl("http://whatismybrowser.com");
```

I get the following error:

> Failed to load the swt-webkit library

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you read SWT faq for [browser as Webkit](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#howusewebkit) and [how to specify default browser type](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserspecifydefault) ..?

Comment: @Sorceror Yes I did. What is not clear to me is where exactly I add the `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=webkit` line. I've put it at the end of eclipse.ini file of my developing eclipse environment cause I figured out this is where the newly launched workspace gets its configurations from when debugging, but still get that error

Comment: `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=webkit` is run command parameter I can say, but furthermore I don't have any experiences with Eclipse plugin and WebKit.. Mozilla rendering core is not enough..? ;] Another tut I've found which might help you [webkit for swt](http://www.genuitec.com/about/labs-webkit-for-swt/WebKit%20For%20SWT%20Developer%20Guide.html).

Comment: @Sorceror I've seen that page already. The problem with that is that is Windows only. The reason I am after WebKit is that I need to do some websokcets and currently WebKit browsers have the best support for it. I'll keep looking and if I find a solution I'll post it. For now I think I'll launch an external browser (hopefully websockets will get better support across all browsers by then)

Comment: GL with that.. I have an idea how to debug the problem. If you'll download the sources of SWT for your platform, attach them to your project and debug into the code where `Browser` instance is created you might find the problem..

Comment: @unexplored Did you get the solution of this problem,Actually i am also facing the same problem when running SWT.WEBKIT.Please help

Comment: @Eshika Not really, I am still launching an external browser. The plugin is to be used by a limited number of people and they're OK with that, so I kind of forgot about this... You just reminded me about it :)

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem too
What you need to do use
JVM : 32bit
SWT :32 bit

set the safari.exe path in your environment settings , (If you are using older version of Windows)

Else if SWT and JVM are not of same 32 bit it will generate error .