# Using WebKit for SWT Browser occurs error on x64 OS

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, safari, webkit, swt

My question is a bit like [unexplored's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117651/using-webkit-for-swt-browser-inside-eclipse-plugin).

My enviroment:

- OS: windows server 2008 r2 (x64)
- Safari installed 5.1.7
- 32 bit SWT (eclipse SDK 3.7.2 * 32)
- 32 bit jvm (32)
- Add `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=webkit` in `eclipse.ini`
- Add `C:\Program Files(x86)\Safari\Apple Application Support` in windows PATH

Code like this:

```
//create Mozilla browser
browser = new Browser(parent, SWT.WEBKIT);  //error was caused here.
```

Error message:

```
Unhandled event loop exception
No more handles [Safari must be installed to use a SWT.WEBKIT-style Browser]
```

With the same configuration,when my os is win7 - 32bit,it works well.

Anybody know why,or tell me how to find the cause?

Thanks very much

Comment: Are you sure that eclipse is running under 32-bit JVM..?

Comment: @Sorceror Yes,i am sure. System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model") = 32

Comment: The only thing I can advise is to download debug version of SWT and try to debug through to see what exactly happens, because it looks like you made all necessary steps to use WebKit in SWT..